# Cross-browser grid of images nested in flex container

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

Having a fixed-height, variable width grid of 'oversized' images (simplified: 2 images only, different only by orientation. In reality, these have various sizes and aspect ratios) inside a `flex` container (simplified: `body`) yields different results depending on the browser:

```css
    body {
        display: flex;
    }

    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 50px;
    }

    .grid>img {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="grid">
    <img alt="portrait"
        src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
    <img alt="landscape"
        src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</div>
</body>
```

The expected result (both same size, aspect ratio preserved, cover) in Chrome 108.x:

[image: Screenshot in Chrome]

and the result in FF 108.x:

[image: Screnshot in FF]

I tried playing with various 'settings' (such as `object-fit: cover`, `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1`, nesting the images / the grid in `div`s with e.g. `display: block`, using [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css), ...) but could not find a working solution.

What do I need to do to get the Chrome behaviour in FF?

Answer (score -1):

Since `width` of 50px seems to matter, use `grid-template-columns` instead of *-rows*, and for the image use `aspect-ratio: 1;` and if you want `object-fit: cover;` to prevent image distortions

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px;
}

.grid>img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img alt="width of img &gt; height of row" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkBAMAAACCzIhnAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAADUExURf///6fEG8gAAAAJcEhZcwAADsEAAA7BAbiRa+0AAAAcSURBVFjD7cEBDQAAAMKg909tDwcEAAAAAByoARPsAAFwJuooAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the question with a less-minimal example, as I'd like to have a 'horizontally responsive' grid, not a fixed width.